# django and instapy integration

Tags: python, django, instapy

I want to build a tool like hootsuide for my own stuff. As you know, Instagram only allows instagram partners to publish a content via api.

I use instapy as a single python file but I've never used with django before. I'm having some troubles with integration.

**views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from instapy import InstaPy
# Create your views here.

def instapy_login(request):
    session = InstaPy(username='test', password='test')
    session.login()
    return redirect("/")
```

However, I want to use this login credentials for next requests.
For example :

```
def fetch_followers(request):
    session = InstaPy(username='test', password='test') # I don't want to login again.
    session.login() # I don't want to login again.
    followers = session.grab_followers(username="test", amount="full")
    print(followers)
    return redirect("/")
```

I don't want to login in every request. Any idea about fixing it? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to django but i think pass instapy_login to your function in which you want to use

Comment: seems more like a comment